# Replace header image on all other pages but home - URL issue

Tags: functions, filters, header-image

I've got a function working to achieve what I want on my dev server, but it will not work on the live site.

I have a random image implemented via shortcode and plugin, and it must appear everywhere EXCEPT the home page.  This is what works on my dev server:

```
add_filter( 'option_woo_options', ‘my_woo_options_filter' );
function my_woo_options_filter( $options ) {

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ( $url !== 'http://www.mydomain.net/' ) {
    $options[ 'woo_logo' ] = do_shortcode( '[random-image attachmentids="380,381,383,384,385,386,387,388,389,390,400" is_header="1"]' );
}

return $options;

}
```

However, it will not work on my new server.  Everything appears to be the same.  The random image replaces the header on all pages, including the home page.

Any suggestions? I need to do this without changing header.php in the theme.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `if ( $url !== 'http://www.mydomain.net/' )` with `if ( !is_home() )`, which is WP's own function that checks if it's the blog's front page.

Comment: We couldn't do that because woothemes get's it's options on the 'init' hook which is run before the 'is_home' knows it's on the front page or not - or so the person who helped me set this up tells me...

Comment: How about $url = home_url(); http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

Comment: Unfortunately, the same problem applies to home_url.  I'm going to resolve it by changing header.php for now.